# Improper use of OpenMP in fortran code increase wall time

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, gfortran

I am trying to parallelize a FORTRAN code, but apparently I am not using the OpenMP statements correctly. I started to implement OpenMP paralelization only for a subroutine to observe expected decrease in the wall time, but it increases total wall time of program instead! Here is the subroutine that I am try to run in parallel. It has common variables and ncell,nnode,node(3,mxc),neigh(3,mxc),xy(2,mxn),area(mxc), mxc and mxn are assigned before gradient is called.
I made the variable ne,Tneigh,Tface,n1,n2 as PRIVATE because they are computed differently in each thread. Is this approach is wrong and is it reason for longer wall time?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
  subroutine  GRADIENT
  parameter (mxc=5001,mxn=3001)
  common /grid/ ncell,nnode,node(3,mxc),neigh(3,mxc),
 >              xy(2,mxn),area(mxc)
  common /var/ time,dt,Tcell(mxc),Tbc(10),outflux(mxc)
  common /grad/ dTdx(mxc),dTdy(mxc)


  !$OMP PARALLEL
  !$OMP  DO PRIVATE(ne,Tneigh,Tface,n1,n2)

  DO n = 1,ncell
  dTdx(n) = 0.
  dTdy(n) = 0.
  do nf = 1,3   
     ne = neigh(nf,n)
     if(ne .gt. 0) then       !..real neighbor
       Tneigh = Tcell(ne)     
     else                     !..other walls
       Tneigh = Tbc(-ne)
     endif
     Tface = 0.5*(Tcell(n)+Tneigh)
     n1 = node(nf,n)
     if(nf .lt. 3) then
        n2=node(nf+1,n)
     else
        n2=node(1,n)
     endif
     dTdx(n) = dTdx(n) + Tface*(xy(2,n2)-xy(2,n1))
     dTdy(n) = dTdy(n) - Tface*(xy(1,n2)-xy(1,n1))
  enddo 
  dTdx(n) = dTdx(n)/area(n)
  dTdy(n) = dTdy(n)/area(n)

  ENDDO

 !$OMP END DO !NOWAIT
 !$OMP END PARALLEL

  return 
  end
```

Edit: The time is measured by omp_get_wtime function and followings are the measurements:
Sequential = 0.5 s
Parallel = 8.4 s  (on average, sometimes it is much more higher I do not know why)

node, neigh and xy 2D arrays are filled with floating point numbers by reading from a dat file and area 1D function is filled with some operations using xy, node and neigh arrays.

Comment: Show your time measurements and the way how you measure the time. Also some details about your hardware (CPU).

Comment: And show the code of `neigh`, `node` and others (if they are functions), or their declaration (if they are arrays). It is not strictly necessary, but I would add `n` and `nf` to the `private` clause.

Comment: More than likely, you're calculating the CPU time of the function instead of the actual wall time of the function. Use `omp_get_wtime()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited the question but I did not put codes directly for simplicity. I do not know exactly the hardware details because I am running code on a HPC server provided my university. In addition I did not add n and nf to private clause because they are default private, aren't they?

Comment: What for simplicity? You are making the job much more difficult for us, if simpler for you, when we have to guess, what the actual code is. I am not going to look in a crystal ball for a solution.

Comment: Why are you so rude? I am saying they are filled with floating numbers in some way and also the sizes are given in the code. I also said, I applied parallelism to only one subroutine in whole code and wall time I measure increased. I think it is clear enough. If you do not want to guess anything, then don't. you do not even have to write anything...